# Is a reduced neutral conductor acceptable on a cord for use with a generator?

Tags: wiring, generator

I purchased a 12,500 watt portable generator, a 50 amp inlet box and the corresponding 50 amp plug to power a friend's residence.  I also purchased a 10’ long 50 amp range cord to connect the generator to the house via the inlet box.  The cord was labeled for 50 amp service with #6/4 wiring.  When I received the cord it came as a 50 amp service with #6/2 & #8/2 wiring.

My question is:
Is it acceptable to use this cord, with the reduced size neutral wire, to connect the generator to the inlet box?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: What are the loads being powered? , cords have different capacity see table 400.5.a.1.

Comment: Just a note on using Table 400.5(A)(1), the text of section 400.5 says a neutral that carries only the imbalance load doesn't count as a current carrying conductor, so column B applies.

Comment: Yeah, because range cord neutrals only need to power the oven light.  Just in case you have a 4800 watt oven light.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to use a *range* cord (SRD) for this application? It's not rated for outdoor usage, for one, and most generators use a *locking* plug for their 50A connections, for two, which your range cord won't fit into....

Answer (score 3):

### Take that range cord back and get the correct cord for the job

50A generator inlet boxes, as well as many generators with 50A outputs, do *not* use anything resembling the NEMA 14-50 that is certainly on the end of your range cord.  Instead, they use *locking* type connectors; unfortunately, there is no such thing as a NEMA L14-50, so California had to step in and set their own standard for this, [the CS6365C/CS6375 family](https://www.stayonline.com/product-resources/reference-california-standard.asp).  Furthermore, the type SRD cordage that is used for range cords is not rated for wet locations or hard/extra-hard usage, making it utterly unsuitable for use outdoors, even if your generator uses a NEMA 14-50R for its 50A receptacle.

As a result, you're better off taking all your stuff back and getting the proper generator cord for your generator.  This will have a CS6364C cord-connector on it to mate with what is almost certainly a CS6375 inlet on the generator inlet box, and be made from extra-hard usage, wet-rated cordage such as type SOOW, with a 6/4 wire configuration, and either a NEMA 14-50P or a CS6365C plug on the other end, depending on what your generator uses.